# Cross join and order by query - Rows updating but not ordering

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

trying to update all the rows in my database and update their 'rank' field depending on what order they are returned.

I have this:

```
    $query = "update blogs cross join (select @rn := 0) vars set build_rank = (@rn := @rn + 1); order by buildpointsNow";
    $query_params = array();
    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        echo 'Updated Rank!';
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    }
```

Which updates all of the rows with an order, but updates them in the order of their ID. Is there a problem with how I am ordering them in the statement?

P.S., not sure how to use bound queries with cross joins.

Comment: Should just need to remove the semi colon.. I don't know php but semi colon ends the query i'm 99% sure.. the semi colon after @rn + 1) that is

Comment: That gives an error for improper use of ORDER BY